# cron job set up in magento on server

Tags: php, magento, cron

I worked on `magento` and I want to run `cron job` on the server.

If I run `domainname/magentofolder/cron.php` in the address bar it works.

But when I try to set up `cron job` on `cpanel` it will not working.

Comment: how is your cron set-up in the cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

If executing the php cron file doesn't work you can also try so set up the cron to use the cron.sh file like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

*/5 * * * * wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/PATH_TO_MAGENTO/cron.php > /dev/null

more information is on [xtento](http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Setting_up_the_Magento_cronjob)